# Ruby on Rails: string method - how to recognize "enter" and re-display it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the data from what other people inserted via a "textarea" in ruby on rails.

They must have clicked "enter" a couple of times. I saved this string data as a variable @input. But if I tried to display it by typing <%=@input%> , then all sentences are connected to together without a clear border that was meant to be there, seeming the enter is not recognized as an "enter".

I think there is a sure way to do it correctly and do you have any suggestion that I can display as the way that input users wanted to display? :)

Looking forward to seeing the opinion from the experts!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is called newlines or line breaks. Rails got a helper method `simple_format` that will replace single newlines with `<br />` tags and double newlines will wrap the previous string in a `<p>` tag

```
<%= simple_format @input %>
```

If you just want every newline character replaced with a break tag you could do it manually by substituting the `\n` character:

```
<%= @input.gsub("\n","<br />") %>
```